# Window location replace - timeout help? Javascript question

Tags: javascript, html

I have had tried to figure a way to add a timeout in my code before it redirects you.
I have googled and found some help but none of them are doing what I expected

> /**** This prompts user what year they were born and calculates age (roughly) */
>   /*****If the user is under 18 takes them to Disneyland, if not they are allowed to enter */

function ageButton() {
    var askDOB = prompt("What year were you born?");

```
if (askDOB > 2002) {
    document.getElementById("agePass").innerHTML = "Access Denied"
    window.location.replace("http://www.disney.com");
}
else {
    document.getElementById("agePass").innerHTML = "Access Granted"
    window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
}
```

}

Just need a way to have a 3 second timeout before it redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setTimeout(function, milliseconds) to do that. something like this:

```
// location replace in 1 second
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.replace("http://www.disney.com");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(() => window.location.replace("http://www.disney.com"), 1000);